# Distinguish knex client from knex transaction

Tags: orm, knex.js

Knex promise-based transactions can be used like regular knex client.

```
const db = knex.transaction() //or just const db = require('knex')(knexOptions)
db('books').insert(books);    // it works in both case
```

I need to accept knex object as an argument of my function and execute transaction inside it.  Can i distingue somehow if knex object or knex transaction passed as argument? In case if this is not a transaction, I want to wrap client object with knex.transaction.

Could I use something like `db.isTransaction` syntax?

```
function myFunc(db) {
if (!db.isTransaction)
  {
    db=knex.transaction()
  }
db('books').insert(books); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `knex.isTransaction` property to tell if the object is a knex transaction or a client.

```js
function myFunction(db) {
  if (db.isTransaction) {
    console.log('Inside transaction')
    return db.from('table_1').select()
  } else {
    console.log('Wrapping client in a transaction')
    return db.transaction(trx => myFunction(trx))
  }
}
```

In both cases, you query should be executed within a transaction